# View controller's data changes on 2nd attempt

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hey my code changes data in another view controller on 2nd attempt on 1st just showing default values

Code inside button

```
@IBAction func check(_ sender: Any) {
    makeRequest()
    let fin = UIStoryboard(name: "FinalViewController", bundle: nil)
    let pop = fin.instantiateInitialViewController()! as! FinalViewController
    pop.img = icon
    pop.state = state
    pop.fail = failed
    self.present(pop, animated: true)   
}
```

Code inside 2nd view controller

```
class FinalViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var weathure_icon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!
    var fail = false
    var img = ""
    var state = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if fail == false{
            super.viewDidLoad()
            status.text = state
            weathure_icon.image = UIImage(named: img+".png")
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `makeRequest()` do?  Is it asynchronous, perhaps?  (Always call `super.viewDidLoad()` rather than putting inside an `if` clause.)

Comment: Did you check whether ```state``` (for example) has the desired value when it's assigned to ```pop.state```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check three things in your code inside the button action.

1. Please cross-check, is **makeRequest()** asynchronous request??
2. is icon, state and failed parameters request coming from **makeRequest()** method, in this case you need to handle request data on main thread.
3. Please replace following in your code:

**This**

let fin = UIStoryboard(name: "FinalViewController", bundle: nil)
let pop = fin.instantiateInitialViewController()! as! FinalViewController

**With**

let fin = UIStoryboard(name: "STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil)
let pop = fin.instantiateInitialViewController(identifier: "FinalViewController")! as! FinalViewController

Hope this will help you and make success with your implementation :)